# Is there any place to host your code online?

Tags: version-control, repository, hosting, revision-history

There are many free online services which provides you with large spaces to store your personal materials, mails, etc. But is there any place that can let us host our code - which keeps the change history?

[Google Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Code) or [SourceForge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SourceForge) may not be a ideal place because it requires creating a project which is specific and useful to others, while what I want is a place to hold any kind of code which I think is useful but may not be for anybody else.

Comment: I believe it is safer and more convenient to access from multiple places, ie, office and home

Comment: I think the word you are looking for is "private".

Comment: Hosting it online not only makes it more accessible, but should something happen to your hard drive you won't all your work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get free GIT and SVN hosting at [unfuddle.com](http://unfuddle.com/)

Comment: Sadly, this was discontinued in 2019.

Answer (score 20):

It's all about [Github](http://www.github.com). 300 MB repository for free. Nice interface, easy to use. Plus we all know GIT > SVN :)

Comment: The help of GitHub states, that there aren't "[any set disk space quotas](https://help.github.com/articles/what-is-my-disk-quota)". The 300 MB limit also was a soft limit.

Answer (score 9):

[BitBucket](http://bitbucket.org) allow for public and private Mercurial repositories.

Answer (score 7):

Github has [Gists](http://gist.github.com/) that might work for you. Also, [Snipplr](http://snipplr.com/).

Answer (score 5):

http://codeplex.com is where MS provides **open source** source control via Team Foundation Server.

Answer (score 5):

[projectlocker](http://projectlocker.com/) is also a good alternative for free Subversion, Git hosting..

Answer (score 4):

You can also get free, private SVN hosting at http://beanstalkapp.com/. Their 100MB package is free.

Answer (score 3):

Google Code [link](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=code&ltmpl=phosting&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fhosting%2F&followup=http%3A%2F%2Fcode.google.com%2Fhosting%2F).

Answer (score 2):

How about http://cvsdude.com/ which paid or http://xp-dev.com/ which is free.

Answer (score 2):

come on guys don't you see that he is interest only in hosting online some  fragments
of code like some functions etc not  full projects and also not public but private.
Of course it is possible with each and every solution you all said in your posts
but it is not exactly what he was looking for .
You all replied like spammers and is that's funny

So why don't you just use http://gist.github.com/

as someone already mentioned

Answer (score 1):

You can host private projects on [DevjaVu](http://www.devjavu.com/) is you want to use Subversion.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.svnhostingcomparison.com/

Answer (score 1):

[CVSDude](http://cvsdude.com/) does free 2M subversion repository, you can also use CVS if you pay.

Comment: Paying for CVS over SVN seems a bit.. backwards

Comment: true, but we don't always get to choose out tools

Answer (score 1):

I've used http://planetsourcecode.com/ to store all sorts of bits of code. Users even upload entire applications.

Answer (score 0):

There are even online code editors available (well, a kind of, that project is still in the development phase).

Linky:  [https://bespin.mozilla.com/](https://bespin.mozilla.com)

Answer (score 0):

I've used CodeSpaces for over a year now and never had a problem. I'm a new user so I apparently can't post links...

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of answers already submitted which are suited to hosting full-fledged applications so I won't bother adding to the list but if you're looking at hosting smaller things (code snippets, simpler projects) with revision history you could consider using a wiki?

Answer (score 0):

I know this was posted 4 years ago, but you could always just sign up on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and have private source code there.

Pastebin has been around since 2002 and is currently "the #1 paste tool". It supports a number of syntaxes (including C++, C, Ruby, and Java. Full list on site.)

**Edit;**

Their PRO plan is only $2.95 USD for one month or $1.99 USD/mo if you purchase for a full year. You can find out more on the limits of free vs Pro [here](http://pastebin.com/pro).

**Edit 2;**

If nothing else, sign up for Dropbox, SkyDrive, or Mediafire and upload your files there.

Answer (score 0):

[Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-team-services-vs) has free, private, unlimited, Git repos for [version control](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/version-control-vs). You also get integrated bug and work item tracking, enterprise [Agile tools](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/agiletools-vs) for [DevOps](https://www.visualstudio.com/features/alm-devops-vs), like backlogs and Kanban boards, automated build, test, and release plus other team capabilities to build and ship apps.

You can connect with Xcode, Eclipse, IntelliJ, Android Studio, Visual Studio, or any dev tool you like.

Team Services is free for the first 5 users with Basic access, plus unlimited stakeholders working on the backlog, and Visual Studio subscribers. Here's [how to get started with Team Services](https://www.visualstudio.com/docs/setup-admin/team-services/sign-up-for-visual-studio-team-services).